# how to use hubspot Conversations sdk on typescript/angular program?

Tags: angular, typescript, hubspot

I got some javascript code form https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/conversation/chat-widget-sdk

```
window.HubSpotConversations.widget.load();
window.HubSpotConversations.widget.refresh();
window.HubSpotConversations.widget.open();
window.HubSpotConversations.widget.close();
```

Now I want to hide or show  HubSpot chat bubble on different pages on a typescript/angular program, any idea about it? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

To hide/remove the Hubspot chat bubble you can use the methods available on window, like:

```
window.HubSpotConversations.widget.remove();
```

to load it again, you can use either:

```
window.HubSpotConversations.widget.load();
```

or, if you want to reset and reload (in case you changed some user info for example):

```
window.HubSpotConversations.widget.resetAndReloadWidget();
```

And also, for typescript you will need to add a type for the elements you are going to use something like:

```
declare global {
  var HubSpotConversations: {
    widget: {
      remove: () => void;
      load: () => void;
    };
  };
}
```

You can check the docs: https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/conversation/chat-widget-sdk

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: As @ConnorLow mentioned, linked resources change overtime. Extracting relevant information from the linked page and including within answer is the best way to ensure future visitors with the same question receive an appropriate answer.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.